# Multiple touch targets in ion-item

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an ion-list where each ion-item has a href to navigate to the next page (master -> detail). So on-tap event of an ion-item it will navigate to the detail page (as expected).

However, I have a button inside each ion-item that performs an action. The issue at hand here is that there are two touch-targets. When tapping on the button inside the ion-item both the button's event is fired as well as the surrounding ion-item's event.

The button inside ion-item uses the ng-click event and the ion-item is fired by the href.

I want to be able to tap the button inside the ion-item without firing the href event on the ion-item.

Answer (score 0):

Add `$event.stopPropogation()` after executing the desired scope function in `ng-click` (the deeper one, which is the button in this case).

**Example:**

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-click="someFunction()">
    List Item
    <button class="button button-small" ng-click="anotherFunction(); $event.stopPropagation();;">List Button</button>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

For the above example, whenever you click the button, only `anotherFunction()` will be executed. When you click the list item, only `someFunction()` will be executed.

Best of luck!

Comment: Hi @Ariel unfortunately that proposed solution didn't work for me

Comment: Can you please show full code? Upload it to CodePen or JSFiddle.